# NoSuchFileException: ingest-geoip after adding volumes to docker-compose file

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I'm using a Docker image that contains Elasticsearch and Kibana and I want to add some local files to docker using `volumes`, after adding this line to `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
volumes:
  - /home/myUsername/elasticsearch/config:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config
```

I got this error when running `docker-compose up`:

```
[...]
elasticsearch    | [2019-01-02T13:16:27,809][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node_1] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
elasticsearch    | [2019-01-02T13:16:27,810][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node_1] loaded plugin [ingest-geoip]
elasticsearch    | [2019-01-02T13:16:27,813][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node_1] loaded plugin [ingest-user-agent]
elasticsearch    | [2019-01-02T13:16:29,504][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [node_1] uncaught exception in thread [main]
elasticsearch    | org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/ingest-geoip
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:140) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    | Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/ingest-geoip
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.IngestGeoIpPlugin.getProcessors(IngestGeoIpPlugin.java:74) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.ingest.IngestService.<init>(IngestService.java:49) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:351) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:252) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:326) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  ... 6 more
elasticsearch    | Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/ingest-geoip
elasticsearch    |  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |  at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:428) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |  at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:465) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |  at java.nio.file.Files.list(Files.java:3527) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.IngestGeoIpPlugin.loadDatabaseReaders(IngestGeoIpPlugin.java:85) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.IngestGeoIpPlugin.getProcessors(IngestGeoIpPlugin.java:72) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.ingest.IngestService.<init>(IngestService.java:49) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:351) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:252) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:326) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
elasticsearch    |  ... 6 more
elasticsearch exited with code 1
```

I checked out `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config` and found `ingest-geoip` already in there:

```
sh-4.2# ls
elasticsearch.yml  ingest-geoip  jvm.options  log4j2.properties  role_mapping.yml  roles.yml  users  users_roles
```

Is there something  I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you check the permissions|process-access to the file. That can also cause it (if ES is running as some other user)

Comment: @v_sukt I got this error even when excuting the `docker-compose up` in `sudo` mode.

Comment: try them individually with docker run - once working handle with docker compose. To debug use ENTRYPOINT/CMD as shell(may be add sleep command for 30m) so that you can get inside container and execute the elasticsearch command to start the service while checking if file exists/is accessible etc. [docker exec -ti <container> /bin/bash(or the shell available in baseimage)]